# Vertically center with variable height

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following problem: I want to center some text vertically. I know, that's not difficult, but I need it to be centered without knowing the height of any of my elements. The height vary that much that I can't give it a certain height.

My HTML DOM:

```
<div class="list">

<div class="plus-sign-box">
    <div class="plus-sign-box-sign"></div>
    <div class="plus-sign-box-text">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <p>

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin…

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="plus-sign-box">
    <div class="plus-sign-box-sign"></div>
    <div class="plus-sign-box-text">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <p>

                Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,…

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
 list {
    font: inherit;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px none;
    margin: 0px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: #444;
}

.plus-sign-box {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.plus-sign-box-text {
    width: 75%;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 55px;
}

.inner-box {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.inner-box p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Vertically center the "+" sign is easy because of it's always 50px height but the text next to it don't have a certain height.

[image: Picture]

Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would solve your issue personally...

The following code shows how you could vertically align your elements via the use of ghost elements...

## **Potential Solution:**

```css
.outer { 
        height: auto; 
        text-align: center; 
        background: #444;
    }

    .outer:before { 
        content: ''; 
        display: inline-block; 
        height: 100%; 
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    span {
        font-size: 50px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    .inner {  
        padding: 10px;
        width: 40rem; 
        display: inline-block; 
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #FFF;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin…</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin… </div>
</div>
```

## **UPDATE:**

Here is a working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0v0m050/) thanks to [suslov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3444240/suslov)

Answer (score 1):

For me the ideal answer is the following site:

[howtocenterincss](http://howtocenterincss.com/)

It is a really great tool for centering in general, you can pick your case and get the best solution. You can even choose the IE versions to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

How about going like this

```
.plus-sign-box-text {
            width: 75%;
            color: #FFF;
            margin-left: 55px;
            height:auto;
    }
```

OR

```
.plus-sign-box-text {
    width: 75%;
    color: #FFF;
    vertical-align:central;
    height:auto;
}
```